# How to set an axis range bigger than value range in devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to set a rangbar chart in devexpress to show the task's range time.

```
        rangeBarChart.Series.Clear();

        Series series = new Series("S1", ViewType.RangeBar);
        series.ValueScaleType = ScaleType.DateTime;

        DateTime stime = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-08-29 8:00");
        DateTime etime = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-08-29 12:00");

        SeriesPoint point = new SeriesPoint("task1", stime, etime);

        series.Points.Add(point);

        rangeBarChart.Series.Add(series);

        ((XYDiagram)rangeBarChart.Diagram).Rotated = true;

        DateTime rangestime = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-08-29 8:00");
        DateTime rangeetime = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-08-29 18:00");

        ((XYDiagram)rangeBarChart.Diagram).AxisY.VisualRange.Auto = false;
        ((XYDiagram)rangeBarChart.Diagram).AxisY.VisualRange.SetMinMaxValues(rangestime, rangeetime);
```

I want the AxisY ranges from 8:00 - 18:00 although the point range from 8:00 to 12:00.
However, the code runs like this[image]

How can I make an axis range bigger than value's range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the overall range of Series associated with the axis you should use the [WholeRange](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.WholeRange.property) property instead of the [VisualRange](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraCharts.AxisBase.VisualRange.property):

```
((XYDiagram)rangeBarChart.Diagram).AxisY.WholeRange.Auto = false;
((XYDiagram)rangeBarChart.Diagram).AxisY.WholeRange.AutoSideMargins = false;
((XYDiagram)rangeBarChart.Diagram).AxisY.WholeRange.SetMinMaxValues(rangestime, rangeetime);
```

Take a look at the [Visual Ranges and Whole Ranges](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/5803/Controls-and-Libraries/Chart-Control/Chart-Elements/Diagram/Axes/Visual-Ranges-and-Whole-Ranges) article for details.